# What weight does a scale show when you throw an object onto it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, collision, intuition

Imagine you have a bucket (cross-sectional area $A$) on top of a scale. Into the bucket you begin to pour sand (density $\rho$) with a mass flow rate of $\dot{m}$. The total weight of the sand in the bucket after time $t$ is $\dot{m} g t$. However, this is not what the scale shows. The height of the sand in the bucket increases linearly as $y(t) = \frac{\dot{mt}}{\rho A}$. (This is true, at least, after the first grain of sand collides with the bottom of the bucket.) That means that the center of mass of the sand in the bucket also increases linearly as $\frac{1}{2} y(t)$. If we consider the force-momentum equation, we can say:

$$F = N - \dot{m} g t = \frac{dp}{dt} = m \frac{dv_\text{CM}}{dt} + v_\text{CM} \frac{dm}{dt}$$

Since $y_\text{CM}$ increases linearly, $\frac{dv_\text{CM}}{dt} = 0$. This gives the normal force (i.e., the scale reading) as:

$$N = \dot{m} g t + \frac{\dot{m}^2}{\rho A} = \boxed{W + \frac{\dot{m}^2}{\rho A}}$$

This means the scale shows *more*, by a constant amount, than the weight of the sand at any time $t$. This is a well-known result, and is one-half the solution to the famous "Hourglass Problem."

There is another way to see the same result. Consider the sand in the bucket with total weight $W$. Then, the scale will show $W - W_\text{ff} + F_\text{collision}$, where $W_\text{ff}$ is the freefall weight and $F_\text{collision}$ is the average collision force from sand coming to a rest at the bottom of the bucket. If the sand falls a height $h$, exactly $\dot{m} g t_\text{ff} = \dot{m} g \sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}} = \dot{m} \sqrt{2gh}$ weight is in freefall. At the bottom of the freefall column, sand is moving at a speed of $\sqrt{2gh}$. Each unit time, $\dot{m}$ mass of sand accelerates from a velocity of $-\sqrt{2gh}$ to some final velocity $u$, meaning the average collision force is $\dot{m} (u + \sqrt{2gh})$.

If we incorrectly take $u = 0$, we get that the collision force exactly compensates for the missing weight in freefall, and the scale will show no excess weight. This is a famous incorrect answer for this problem. In fact, because the height of the sand is moving upward at a speed of $\frac{\dot{m}}{\rho A}$, we should consider the relative speed of the freefalling sand with respect to this surface. Taking $u = \frac{\dot{m}}{\rho A}$, we recover:

$$N = W - W_\text{ff} + F_\text{collision} = W - \dot{m} \sqrt{2gh} + \frac{\dot{m}^2}{\rho A} + \dot{m} \sqrt{2gh} = \boxed{W + \frac{\dot{m}^2}{\rho A}}$$

Since sand is a conglomerate of small rocks, I naively expect the behavior of a single rock to follow this same analysis. Consider a single rock with mass $M$ being dropped onto a scale. If it falls a height $h$, it achieves a maximum speed of $\sqrt{2gh}$. It *presumably* decelerates from this speed to $0$ over a collision time $\tau$. For that $\tau$ time, the scale should show an average weight of:

$$N = \frac{M \sqrt{2gh}}{\tau}$$

However, this does not seem like the full story. In the first analysis of sand, there was an acceleration of the center of mass which seems to be absent here. In the second analysis of the sand, there was an additional relative velocity $u$ which increased the collision force, which seems to be absent here. Are these effects actually present in the case of a single rock, despite how small they might be?

---

My thought is the following. When the bottom of the rock hits the scale, it sends a pressure wave at the speed of sound through the rock. At every other point in the rock, the molecules seem to fall into a surface which is moving toward it due to the pressure wave, **not a stationary surface**. In that sense, the pressure wave generated by the normal force does not cause these molecules to stop, but rather to change direction from a velocity of $-\sqrt{2gh}$ to a velocity of $u$. If I then split this rock into many small rocks (i.e., take the limit approaching sand), this effect persists and exactly explains the excess weight in the sand case.

My trepidation here is when I say "speed of sound," I am now introducing some Young's modulus $E$ into the mix which I have not yet considered. It seems there should be a more elegant argument in the case of a single rock which neatly extends to the case of many infinitesimally small rocks.